# How do I connect database via ssh using gorm in golang?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to connect to database via ssh, I am using the `database/sql` package to connect to the database, but I don't understand how to implement the `database/sql` to the gorm `jinzhu/gorm`. Can somebody tell me how to implement it? Or is there any way to connect by just using gorm package?
I am fairly new to golang.

This is what the code looks like.
The main problem is in `NewBrandsRepository` method which cannot use type `*sql.DB` as `*gorm.DB`

```
// Connect to the SSH Server
sshcon, errSSH := ssh.Dial("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", sshHost, sshPort), sshConfig)
if errSSH != nil {

}

defer sshcon.Close()

// Now we register the ViaSSHDialer with the ssh connection as a parameter
mysql.RegisterDial("mysql+tcp", (&ViaSSHDialer{sshcon}).Dial)

// And now we can use our new driver with the regular mysql connection string tunneled through the SSH connection
db, errDB := sql.Open("mysql", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@mysql+tcp(%s)/%s", dbUser, dbPass, dbHost, dbName))

if errDB != nil {

    fmt.Printf("Failed to connect to the db: %s\n", errDB.Error())

}

fmt.Printf("Successfully connected to the db\n")

test := NewBrandsRepository(db)
```

and the `NewBrandsRepository` method is this

```
type brandsRepositoryImpl struct {
    db *gorm.DB
}

func NewBrandsRepository(db *gorm.DB) *brandsRepositoryImpl {
    return &brandsRepositoryImpl{db}
}
```

Comment: share what you have tried; we can help fill up gaps

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava Ok, sir. I have edited the question

Comment: I have added a answer see if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep doing the same steps but instead of sql.Open use

```
dsn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@mysql+tcp(%s)/%s", dbUser, dbPass, dbHost, dbName)
db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
```

Comment: some correction, because that gave me an error. Thank you providing me the code tho

dsn :=  fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@mysql+tcp(%s:%s)/%s", dbUser, dbPass, dbHost, db.Port, dbName)
db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})

Comment: @FajarS.Salviro I seems to have missed that part thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
package mysql_conn

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"

    sqlD "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

func GetMysqlConnSSH(sshUser, sshUrl, sshKeyfilePath, mysqlUser, mysqlPassword, mysqlAddr, mysqlDBName string) *gorm.DB {
    config := ssh.ClientConfig{
        User:            sshUser,
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    }
    key, err := os.ReadFile(sshKeyfilePath)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    signer, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    config.Auth = []ssh.AuthMethod{
        ssh.PublicKeys(signer),
    }
    cli, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", sshUrl, &config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    sqlD.RegisterDial("mysql+ssh", (&Dialer{client: cli}).Dial)
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@mysql+ssh(%s)/%s?charset=utf8mb4", mysqlUser, mysqlPassword, mysqlAddr, mysqlDBName)
    db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return db
}

type Dialer struct {
    client *ssh.Client
}

func (v *Dialer) Dial(address string) (net.Conn, error) {
    return v.client.Dial("tcp", address)
}
```